# Getting access to various elements using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently working on something to check a box and change the text next to it to a hyperlink once ticked

```
<li class="myList">
<input class="myCheckBox" type="checkbox" name="frank"  value="someVal"/>
<span style="dispaly:none;">
<a class="navigation">mylink</a>
</span>
<span>myLink</span>
</li>
<li class="myList">
<input class="myCheckBox" type="checkbox" name="frank"  value="someVal"/>
<span style="dispaly:none;">
<a class="navigation">mylink</a>
</span>
<spanmyLink></span>
</li> .. and so on
```

Hopefully from this you can gather i have 2 items, and i want one visible as default until checkbox is ticked and the hyperlink span tag takes over from the default span tag. That changes to `style="display:none"` other becomes `style="display:block"`

Now for the jQuery

```
$(window).load(function(){
          $('.myCheckBox').click(function(){
           //DO DOMETHING
          });       
      });
```

But once I make the click event occur how to i gain access to these spans and such in order to change the styles of the various elements etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would go from `this`, which is the current element then use any of [the tree traversal functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) to move around the DOM, for example:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('.myCheckBox').change(function() {
    $(this).next("span").toggle(this.checked);
  });       
});
```

In the above we're using [`.toggle(bool)`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to do the hiding/showing, this allows us to hide/show the `<span>` depending on whether the checkbox we care about is checked.

Comment: @Nick: Thanks for the reply. So I can get access to the span, say I want to pull the text of the second span tag in the example above how would I go about doing that?

Comment: @Uncle - If you wanted the "mylink" span it'd be something like `.next().next()` or `.closest("li").find("span:last")`, `.siblings("span:last")`.

Comment: @Nick: Brilliant! but it only works if i use the .click event rather than the .changed any ideas why? P.S used .siblings('span:last')

Comment: @Uncle - are you using `.change()` or `.changed()`?

Comment: @Nick: Tried both with no luck(I assume of course JQuery only makes use of one of them though)

Comment: @Uncle - it should be working, no sure what the issue is...something else would seem to be wrong in your page, check the error console and make sure it's clear.